# How to perform ActionListener() in eclipse

Tags: actionlistener

Actually, I want to perform pure mouse actions(Clicking buttons, selecting check boxes, and select radio button)based upon the GUI label(name), But all the tutorials are given the example to perform with JFrame which we have created.

These examples makes me confusing.

Honestly I'm not professional developer. My professional is testing(QA), but I believe I have sufficient programming knowledge to understand the code. Please give me some sample that i can perform in eclipse IDE.

Note:

The objective of my question is:

How to perform the ActionEvent() in existed iDE?(The frame have File menu, Edit menu and so on.) Is it possible to do with Java?

Please share your ideas with me.

Thanks in advance.

Santhosh.

Comment: Maybe this will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668718/java-mouselistener

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a frame.
2. Put a button into it.
3. Call the `addActionListener` class and add a ActionLister object
   into it.
4. Override the `actionPerformed` method inside the anonymous inner
   class.

As your question talks specifically about eclipse. You should use a plugin called [window builder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/), built by google. It helps you handle action events.

[image]

Read the oracle's documentation for learning. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

I can't write all the code here. But just to get you started here's a link. http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/278-how-add-actionlistener-jbutton-swing.html.

Comment: Thank you so much deepak. I will go through the link which was posted by you.     Still I have a question is it not possible to done this task by Java API(Written code by manually)? instead of trying to install plugins in eclipse?   The purpose of this question to make courser movement and clicking actions in eclipse IDE based upon the label(Which normally done by actionlistener).

Comment: its very much possible, but considering you do not have a background in it, you suggested this plugin. I'd started in the same manner because its easy.

Comment: Thank you so much deepak for your response. I will try it and post my updates.