# Listener for button press wherever in the frame

Tags: java, swing, listener

I have a frame and it has to listen to button press whatever element is selected. Is it possible to make a global listener for this frame, or I have to write listeners for every element I have?

Comment: what do you want to do with the Button? It makes no sense to me listening like this.

Comment: Do you have references of buttons created?

Answer (score 0):

Write a MouseListener/MouseAdapter and share the same instance with all the elements you want to react to.

This other question will give you a clue:
[Java MouseListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668718/java-mouselistener)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is what you want.
You can make those buttons use the same action listener,

```
//set up some buttons...
bt1 = new JButton("BUTTON1");
bt2 = new JButton("BUTTON2");
//use the same actionListener
bt1.addActionListener(someActionListener);
bt2.addActionListener(someActionListener);
```

then in actionPerformed method you can check which button was pressed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JButton pressedButton = (JButton)e.getSource();

//check which button was pressed

    if(pressedButton ==bt1)
        System.out.println("Button 1 do something");
    else if(pressedButton ==bt2)
        System.out.println("Button 2 do something");
}
```