# How to display a JLabel on hovering over a JList item?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JList:

```
    comandaListModel = new SortedListModel<String>();
    comandaListScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    comandaPanel.add(comandaListScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    comandaList = new JList<String>(comandaListModel);
    comandaListScrollPane.setViewportView(comandaList);
```

And I have a custom JLabel class:

```
public class QrCodeLabel extends JLabel {

    public Image qrCode;

    public QrCodeLabel(JList list) {
        super("");
        updateQrCode(list);

    }

    public void updateQrCode(JList list) {
        if (ComandaCreationFrame.getQrMatrixes() != null) {
            this.qrCode = QRGenerator.generateImage(ComandaCreationFrame.getQrMatrixes().get(list.getSelectedValue())).getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.qrCode));
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

The JLabel gets updated on the `valueChanged` of the JList's `ListSelectionListener`. How could I "pop-up" the JLabel on hovering the mouse over each item of the JList? Is it possible to implement such "tool-tip" functionality to a JList? (By "showing" a JLabel, it could also mean a JPanel with a JLabel on it, of course).

Comment: [`JToolTip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolTip.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement MouseAdapter to track what the mouse does when certain actions are performed.

MouseAdaptor comes with 5 MouseEvent methods called "mousePressed", "mouseReleased", **"mouseEntered"**, "mouseExited", and "mouseClicked".
The "mouseEntered" method is what you would use for this.

You will also need to import these:

```
java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
```

Create a constructor in the class that has your JList and, simply add this code inside it:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Inside the mouseEntered method is where you should call your updateQrCode method. So every time the mouse enters the list, the JLabel gets updated.

For more information, see this thread: [Java MouseListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668718/java-mouselistener)

I hope this helped.